# active class on multiple navigations set and remove with jquery

Tags: jquery, navigation

Hi i am trying to create a script that will add class active on a tag, and remove others inside the ul.

it works now, but when i have more than one navigation it will toggle them all. 
So how do i make it so it only targets inside the current ul li items?

my codepen for working example: https://codepen.io/andrelange91/pen/JZOawY

**My Html:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="smallNav activeNav">
      <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary">
        <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link active" aria-expanded="true">
            Profile
          </a> 
        </li> 
        <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link">
            Settings
          </a>
        </li>
        <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
          <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link">
            Options
          </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="largeNav activeNav">

    <ul role="tablist" class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-primary flex-column">
      <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link active" aria-expanded="true">
          Profile
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link">
          Settings
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" role="tablist" href="#undefined" class="nav-link">
          Options
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The script i am working on:**

```
$('.activeNav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.activeNav ul').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this the following

```
$('.activeNav li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.activeNav').find('a').removeClass('active');//from the current element find the closest parent with the class activeNav and then find all links to remove the active class
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Can you expand on *"Use this the following"*?

Comment: you need to get links from your current menu not all the menus so you need to go up the dom to the activeNav of the current clicked element , after that select all the links in that activeNav and remove the active class